# JDO + PostgreSQL Arrays

Tags: arrays, postgresql, jdo

I've implemented store_mapping extension but it currently uses ObjectAsStringMapping. As a result I can read array values from database but any insert or update causes underlying postgresql driver error "INTEGER[]" is not "VARCHAR".

Is there any way to implement PGSQL arrays in JDO? It looks quite flexible with all that extension points. Any hints on extension points I have to implement are appreciated, thanks in advance!

**Edit:**

I'm using postgres int8 as a bit field as a "replacement" for arrays after I figured out that I'll be okay with 63 possible values.

Sample class would be:

```
@PersistenceCapable(detachable="true", table="campaigns")
public class Campaign  implements Serializable {

    @PrimaryKey
    @Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
    public Long id;

    public List<Integer> regions;
}
```

And I think I have to implement some mapping from List to java.sql.Array but still didn't figure out how to do that. I could write extension and override default behavior but what extension-point should it be?

Comment: I have a similar issue (maybe?) I want to read a postgresql table which contains a text[] column. How do I have to define my metadata in order to get a String[] or Collection<String>?

Comment: After a lot of searching and code-digging I've ended up with "manual" management of those fields using "raw" sql queries (javax.jdo.query.SQL):
    
`Query q = pm.newQuery("javax.jdo.query.SQL", query);`
`q.setResultClass(Map.class);` There's a ARRAY JDBC type, but it looks like only Hibernate can handle that after adding some support types. I'm not talking about multi-dimensional arrays, for some reason java is too far from this at the moment. Good luck anyway =)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to build a custom field strategy to handle the mapping.

The key then is to transform the representation in this case to PostgreSQL array representation, namely a comma separated value (with `"` escaping text with any special characters but can be used on all values, double quotes are escaped by doubling them). The string is then bracketed betweed `{` and `}`.  So `ARRAY[1,2,3]::int[]` becomes `'{1,2,3}'` or `'{"1","2","3"}'`